# How to achieve multi tenancy with Asp.net Identity 2.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin, asp.net-identity-2

I have just finished implementing the new two factor authentication using OWIN in our new MVC site. Can you please guide me how to achieve multi tenancy with OWIN authentication.

Is there any sample i can look at? Please share your ideas!

Comment: Multi-tenancy has nothing to do with your login method. What exactly do you want to make multi-tenancy-enabled? Your database entries? Then you can for example give each table an `Owner` column, where you store the user ID per row when they create an entry.

Comment: Let's say we have two domains handled by the same site. FacebookAppID & secret is different for both domains. I need a way to set different Facebook app Ids based on the url. HttpContext.Request.Url doesn't work in Startup.Auth.cs

Answer (score 1):

You can find example of that at github from the following link.

https://github.com/JSkimming/AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.Multitenant

Comment: please check user3219798's comment. How can we achieve multi-tenant social login?

Comment: I think there you need to create your own implementation.

Comment: ASP.NET Identity is not suitable for this type of use where setting external login provider settings dynamically during runtime.  It's the biggest draw back of the 2.0 Identity system.